# How to use ffmpeg to add multiple audio files to the video at a specific time?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have an example

ffmpeg -i zs_712922_CT.mp4 -itsoffset 10 -i ct.m4a -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -preset ultrafast -y out1.mp4 
（I don't know why this dropped the video, leaving only the audio.）

to

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -itsoffset 10 -i ct.m4a -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -itsoffset 50 -i ct.m4a -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy  -shortest -y out.mp4

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg -i zs_712922_CT.mp4 -itsoffset 10.555 -i ct.m4a -itsoffset 20.999 -i ct.m4a -itsoffset 70 -i ct.m4a -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0 -c:v copy -preset ultrafast -f mp4 -y out1.mp4

Comment: You can copy the audio. And this method relies on edit lists in the MP4, which some players, like WMP, don't support.